# How to use extra arguments passed with Variable file - Robot framework

Tags: python, robotframework

In Robot Framework user guide there is a section that describes how to pass variable files and also some possible variables if needed. 
Example:
`pybot --variablefile taking_arguments.py:arg1:arg2`

My question is can i use these possible variables arg1 and arg2 in the taking_arguments.py file afterwards and if i can then how?

Right now i have this:

`pybot --variablefile taking_arguments.py:arg1:arg2`

taking_arguments.py contents:

`IP_PREFIX = arg1`

But that results in

`NameError: name 'arg1' is not defined`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The only way to use variables in an argument file using the `--variablefile filename.py:arg1:arg2` syntax is to have your variable file implement the function `get_variables`. This function will be passed the arguments you specify on the command line, and must return a dictionary of variable names and values.

For example, consider the following variable file, named "variables.py":

```
def get_variables(arg1, arg2):
    variables = {"argument 1": arg1,
                 "argument 2": arg2,
                }
    return variables
```

This file creates two robot variables, named `${argument 1}` and `${argument 2}`. The values for these variables will be the values of the arguments that were passed in. You might use this variable file like this:

```
pybot --variablefile variables.py:one:two ...
```

In this case, the strings "one" and "two" will be passed to `get_variables` as the two arguments. These will then be associated with the two variables, resulting in `${argument 1}` being set to `one` and `${argument 2}` being set to `two`.

Comment: Received ```TypeError: get_variables() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)``` when I tried the example above. This is my setup: one robot file with ```open browser``` and these two arguments ```${argument 1}``` and ```${argument 2}``` I am also calling the .py file in the ```Settings``` my command line execution looks like this ```pybot -v variables.py:username:password file.robot``` I am trying to pass a username and password to a form via the command line using this method, but no luck.

Comment: @Freddy You've probably used wrong argument. You should use lowercase `-v` to define single variable. For variable file, use uppercase `-V` or `--variablefile`

Comment: @sjudǝʊ Thank you for this clarification. In fact, I was passing the wrong flag. Using ```-V``` worked as expected. I still received the following error ```Error in file '.../_robot/file.robot': Processing variable file '.../_robot/variables.py' failed: TypeError: get_variables() takes exactly 2 arguments (0 given)``` in the logs, however, the process worked. Not sure if the error from the logs is just something that RF has trouble processing.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't tried to pass initial values to variables in a variable file... So I am not sure if this is something possible...

I can offer an alternative...

You can define manually some variables with their values at the pybot command...

```
pybot -variablefile taking_arguments.py -v IP_PREFIX:arg1 -v Varibale:Value
```

If I am not mistaken these manually initiated variables have a higher priority than these in the variable file. So even if they are initiated in the variable file, the values passed with the -v option will be used in the testcase.

Hope this can help you!